# Intellij - how to make a plugin that can perform IDE actions via a CLI or web service?

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line-interface, intellij-plugin

I need some help getting started making a specific IntelliJ plugin.

I want to make an IntelliJ plugin that makes it so you can launch intelliJ actions from CLI (or from a web service if it's easier).

For example, I'm done building my project with a gradle script... but i want to get it ready in intelliJ too. Right now I have to do this manually with a point-and-clicks.

Instead I want to have this the ability to externally trigger some IntelliJ commands. In my example I would want to fire off these requests from my gradle script:

- `run-intellij-command {project-path} --action refresh-gradle`
- `run-intellij-command {project-path} --action build-project`
- `run-intellij-command {project-path} --action start-debugging --configurationName={configuration-name}`

Does anyone have an example of how I can get started with this?

Really hoping there is an intellij plugin project that already does something similar like reacting to cli commands or hosts a web service that can be called?

Thanks!

Also created this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184885
hoping to see this feature become a reality some day

Comment: did you end up building this plugin? If yes, do you mind sharing it? Would be great help! Thanks!

Comment: I did but I don't have anything I can share at the moment. When I get a moment to share I will send u a msg here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ApplicationStarterEx](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/application/ApplicationStarterEx.java) interface to implement that. Provide a class implementing the interface, and register it in your plugin.xml as the `<appStarter>` extension point.

To execute your code, use Tools | Create Command-line Launcher, and then run `idea <startername> <arguments>` from the command line, where `startername` is what you return from `ApplicationStarter.getCommandName()`.

I'm not aware of any existing open-source plugins that implement similar functionality.

Comment: Most excellent. even these few sentences are an amazingly helpful starting point

Comment: I use this approach to run format and rearrange from CLI in CI.
https://github.com/funbiscuit/idea-formatter-plugin