# Run intellij plugin from cli in Windows 10

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin that analyzes source code in a project. Now I need to run it on a great number of projects, so I decided to automate the process. Looking for a way to achieve this I found that I need to implement ApplicationStarter interface and declaring it as extension point in appStart category, as described here:
[Intellij - how to make a plugin that can perform IDE actions via a CLI or web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817421/intellij-how-to-make-a-plugin-that-can-perform-ide-actions-via-a-cli-or-web-se) 
Although, I was not able to execute my custom command. When I run

```
idea64 mycommand
```

a loading screen of intellij starts and then nothinng happens. I have to kill the process via task manager. My version Is 2020 on Windows 10.
I'm writing here too as on jetbrains I've received no answers yet.
Is there something i'm missing? Thank you in advance.